# Collect $_POST data from multiple pages

Tags: php, post

I'm just thinking about what's the best way of sending $_POST data from page to page. Let's look at the scenario below:

We have 3 pages: A, B, C

On the page A there is a form which collects some data and sending it to the page B. However, the B page also has another form but I want to send both previous received data from page A and form of page B to the page C so all data will be available in the page C.

First of all I thought of storing A page form $_POST data in the session so it may be available from page C with post data from page B, but I'm wondering if there is more practical way to do it.

What do you think? What's your opinion about that?

Greetings!

Comment: What is unpractical about using a session? It is what I would use.

Comment: Maybe you can build a multi step form? or is that in your case not an option?

Answer (score 2):

After submitting A page you can store the data to B page in hidden fields. That way when submitting B page all the data from A page and B page will be available in the C page

Comment: Okay, that's for sure some way to achieve it but the user may modify data from hidden fields via html so I think that I need another validation for that to secure it more :)

Comment: To prevent that are workarounds. For example, you can post A to B, set the hidden fields, set the form action to `C.php?id=XXXXXXXX` where `XXXXXXXX` can be the `md5()` of all the A fields concatenated, and on the C file you can check if the hidden files concatenated and hashed matches the `id` value passed via `get`.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround will be saving form A values to a temp file on the server, and the retrieving the values on C and deleting the file afterwards.